# Favicon is not displayed when sending my website as a link

Tags: html, reactjs, json, favicon

I don't understand why my favicon does not appear when sending my website as a link.

In the index.html:

```
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
      <title></title>
   </head>
```

In the manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your logic is faulty. How you "send" your website is irrelevant. Either the file is there at the correct path or it isn't.

Comment: I'm guessing he has it cached locally from a previous working version or it only works on local dev and not prod

Comment: What does the meta tag look like in the rendered markup? Does that match the final location of the image file?

Comment: The code and the path ate correct, but still, i can't see the favicon when sending the website as a URL